# Laravel Scout Datatable Updating

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-livewire, laravel-scout

I am using Laravel Scout with Algolia for populating a datatable and have this intermittent issue where a record in the table after delete will still be visible. It happens when Algolia's index doesn't update quickly enough and the application fetches the data from Algolia prior to it showing as deleted. After refreshing the page and/or updating another record it shows the correct data. Below is my setup - does anyone have any ideas on how to better set this up so any live update will always have the correct data?

```
    public function deleteSelected()
    {
        $truckings = Trucking::query()->whereKey($this->selected);

        $truckings->each(fn ($trucking) => $trucking->delete());

        event(new TruckingCreated);

        $this->showDeleteModal = false;

        $this->notify('You\'ve deleted ' . collect($this->selected)->count() . ' trucking slips.');

        $this->getRowsQueryProperty();

        $this->selected = [];
    }
```

As you can see I am calling `$this->getRowsQueryProperty();` method after deleting records to force it to update - but there are still instances where this will happen.

Below is that method for reference which fetches the data.

```
    public function getRowsQueryProperty()
    {
        $query = Trucking::search($this->filters['search'],
            function (SearchIndex $algolia, string $query, array $options) {

            $options['filters'] = $this->algoliaFilters();

            return $algolia->search($query, $options);
        });

        return $this->applySorting($query);
    }
```

Thank you for any help or advice.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing a similar issue. Found anything of use?

Comment: @JeremyBelolo In my case this issue was caused by wrapping the statement in DB::transaction(). I removed the transaction and it worked properly. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're missing the `get` call from your query. Using `each` without `get` first chunks the results and runs a mass `delete` query, bypassing model events, thus not deleting indexes.

```php
$truckings = Trucking::query()->whereKey($this->selected)->get();
$truckings->each(fn ($trucking) => $trucking->delete());
```

Comment: Thanks @jrcamatog but this still has the same issue. The model events are working both the original way and with your suggestion. I did test with using ```->get()``` but the synchronization still is off 7/10 times.